# Windows 10 Disabled Audio Playback Devices keep coming back

Tags: windows-10, audio

The two Dell monitors have ability to attach a speaker but they do not currently have one.

I disable them in the Windows Sound Control Panel but they keep coming back. Not every reboot but once every few weeks or more. I can't find what sets it off.

[Windows Sound Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKXqc.png)

[Select Playback Device List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQbS4.png)

Comment: Have you tired uninstalling the speaker drivers from device manager? I'm guessing that whenever the PC loses connection to the monitors and regains connectivity (Powering them off/Unplugging them), it automatically installs/enables the speakers in Windows.

Comment: I did try disabling them in device manager. I thought if I just uninstall them they will install the next reboot? I turn everything off each night, PC and displays. It seems they are always there in device manager, they just get randomly reenabled in the Sound Control Panel.